# Bootstrap a debian build environment and build source packages with no root privileges

Tags: debian, bash, debian-squeeze, packaging, patch-management

On debian `squeeze`, I am trying to do the following :

- fetch sources package from the `wheezy` source repository
- bootstrap a `squeeze` chroot for several architectures
- build the packages for several architectures (`i386`, `amd64`, `all`  and `any`)

I want both the fetching, bootstrapping and build operation to be scriptable, repeatable, and run as a normal user. For the environment setup, I want to make as little use of the `root` account as possible (install the necessary dependencies, and maybe some `visudo` stuff). If possible I would like to avoid using a VM (pbuilder with `user mode linux`)

So far I have tried several things with `pbuilder` (require `root`), `debootstrap` (require `root`) with little success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the working solution uses `pbuilder` and `sudo`.

- After installing both, one has to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file (using `visudo`) and allow users in the group `pbuilder` to run `pbuilder` without a password.

  ```
  %pbuilder ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pbuilder
  ```
- Add the `pbuilder` group and your build user name `builduser` to it

  ```
  root@debian# groupadd pbuilder
  root@debian# gpasswd -a builduser pbuilder
  ```

You will now be able to bootstrap a Debian `chroot` and build packages using `pbuilder` as non-root.

Here is an example script that

- fetches the source package given as the first parameter (as `builduser`, using the answer to [that question](https://serverfault.com/questions/447457/use-apt-get-source-on-a-debian-repo-without-using-etc-apt-source-list))
- build packages from sources, for both `i386` and `amd64` architectures
- upload them with `dput` to an external repositories given by the second parameter of the script

```bash
#/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

THIS=`readlink -f ${0}`
THIS_DIR=`dirname ${THIS}`

PACKAGE=${1}
TARGET_CODENAME=${2}

ARCHS='i386 amd64'
APT_CONF=${THIS_DIR}/tmp/etc/apt.conf

pushd ${THIS_DIR}/src
apt-get update -c ${APT_CONF}
apt-get source ${PACKAGE} -c ${APT_CONF}
popd

for ARCH in ${ARCHS}
do
  BUILD_DIR=${THIS_DIR}/build/${ARCH}
  sudo pbuilder --create --configfile ${BUILD_DIR}/pbuilderrc \ 
                --buildresult ${BUILD_DIR}/
  sudo pbuilder --build --configfile ${BUILD_DIR}/pbuilderrc \
                --buildresult ${BUILD_DIR}/ ${THIS_DIR}/src/${PACKAGE}*.dsc
  dput ${TARGET_CODENAME} ${BUILD_DIR}/*.changes
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use '*fakeroot*' program. Usage of this program - just use instead sudo.

Fakeroot exists in the debian repo, try to *sudo apt-get install fakeroot*

Comment: usage of fakeroot is quite cool, however the build product still is owned by root after compilation and I can't change de packages as a normal user.